Proving (or disproving) $\Pr[A \cap B \cap C] \geq \Pr[A \cap B] - \Pr[C]$
Suppose we have three non-empty events: $A$, $B$, and $C$.
How do we prove (or disprove) that $\Pr[A \cap B \cap C] \geq \Pr[A \cap B] - \Pr[C]$?
Here is what I have done so far. We know that (by the law of total probability):
$$\Pr[A \cap B] = \Pr[A \cap B \cap \overline{C}] + \Pr[A \cap B \cap C],$$
thus, we have
$$\Pr[A \cap B \cap C] = \Pr[A \cap B] - \Pr[A \cap B \cap \overline{C}].$$
We know that $\Pr[\overline{C}] \geq \Pr[A \cap B \cap \overline{C}]$ and $\Pr[\overline{C}] = 1 - \Pr[C]$, thus, we have
\begin{align*}
1-\Pr[C] &\geq \Pr[A \cap B \cap \overline{C}], \text{ or} \\
-\Pr[A \cap B \cap \overline{C}] &\geq \Pr[C]-1.
\end{align*}
Substituting this result back to the previous equation yields
\begin{align*}
\Pr[A \cap B \cap C] \geq \Pr[A \cap B] + \Pr[C] - 1,
\end{align*}
how do we reason that we have
$$\Pr[A \cap B \cap C] \geq \Pr[A \cap B] - \Pr[C],$$
because based on this kind of derivation, we should have $\Pr[C] \geq \frac{1}{2}$.
It seems that we need to have $\Pr[C] \geq \frac{1}{2}$ for the inequality to hold.
(Edited: $A$, $B$, and $C$ are non-empty; grammar.)

It is clearly false when $C$ is the empty set.

Note that in original question, there is only $A\cap B$, so treat it as an event $X:=A\cap B$. Then the question is same as $\mathbb{P}[X\cap C]\ge \mathbb{P}[X]-\mathbb{P}[C]$. But when $X,C$ are disjoint this certainly fail by symmetricity.

@geetha290krm I edited the problem so that all events are non-empty.

@AngaeMT If we require that $\Pr[C] \geq \frac{1}{2}$, does the inequality hold?

$P(C)\ge \frac 1  2$ is necessary: Take $A=B=\Omega$.

It’s false in general. Use Venn diagram to visualize it

@lqazra Actually both $\mathbb{P}[X],\mathbb{P}[C]\ge0.5$ are necessary condition.

Also false whenever $C = A \cap B$ and $\mathrm{Pr}[A \cap B] > 0$.

True when $P(C) \ge \frac 1 2$. Quite easy to prove.
